# how to change output result display

Tags: python-3.x

i made a query in python and got this message back. I would like to present it differently, how can I sort it out?

it looks like this:

```
testsearch {
  "failures": [],
  "successes": [
    {
      "name": "testsearch",
      "result": "200- (Values displayed after dir names are Files/Megs/Age)\r\n200- Doing case-insensitive search for 'testdir ':\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir1 (43F/1942.9M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir2 (25F/1012.1M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir3 (27F/450.5M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir4 (52F/2337.4M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir5 (28F/1157.1M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir6 (29F/493.9M/14d 3h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir7 (49F/2205.5M/9d 0h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir8 (27F/1112.7M/9d 0h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir9 (29F/496.0M/9d 0h)\r\n200- /home/user1/testdir10 (56F/2559.1M/9d 0h)\r\n200- 18 directories found.\r\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is how it should look:

```
/home/user1/testdir2 (25F/1012.1M/14d 3h)
/home/user1/testdir3 (27F/450.5M/14d 3h)
/home/user1/testdir4 (52F/2337.4M/14d 3h)
/home/user1/testdir5 (28F/1157.1M/14d 3h)
/home/user1/testdir6 (29F/493.9M/14d 3h)
/home/user1/testdir7 (49F/2205.5M/9d 0h)
/home/user1/testdir8 (27F/1112.7M/9d 0h)
/home/user1/testdir9 (29F/496.0M/9d 0h)
/home/user1/testdir10 (56F/2559.1M/9d 0h)
```

can someone help me how I can display the output? The number of directories is always different

Answer (score 0):

It should be interesting to see your personal approach and work on it !
Because the number of directories are always different, you need to use dynamic methodology.

From what I see, you have a data object which looks like to JSON format.
You should use the [python built-in package named json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to extract the string on your "result" key.

When this will be done, you should use the [python split method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/string-split). You could for example specify *'split('\r\n')'* which will split your string at each *'\r\n'* and include each part of a string in a list.

Finally you should use the [python regex package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to identify the lines which interest you in order to display them. It may seem complicated but regex it's very powerful and completely match with your needs. You have a lot of tutorials on the internet.

If you want, post your code, tell me what you tried and what didn't work. I will then give you some hints.